# Is "samuraily" correct?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, etymology, meaning-in-context

> Pahlavāni, knighthood, and **samuraily** may be different in forms of
> cultural output, but all three are inherently from the same
> historical essence.

Pahlavāni (پهلوانی) is a Persian word. In its historical context, It means the same as knighthood, i.e. knightly traditions. Now by which word can I refer to the knightly traditions of the samurai class? Is the word "samuraily" possible grammatically and etymologically?

Comment: No, you just use the term samurai. Samurai traditions/class etc.

Comment: Samurai is Japanese. Also, beware of cultural output with an s. Sounds foreign. Why are you mixing Persian and Japanese concepts??

Comment: Because all three are inherently from the same historical essence. :) Heraldry drew me to the conclusion: Nishan (نشان), Arms, and mon (紋) are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell "samuraily" isn't a thing because the first link you find googling it is this page :). The best term is **the way of the samurai**: a familiar phrase, and one based directly on the Japanese term for it:　武士道 (bushido, or samurai way).

Comment: Why not just "bushido"? It is common enough in English that many English dictionaries include it (often, though not always, capitalized).

Comment: There are often multiple ways to solve a problem. I expect when I say "bushido" for people to say "What's that?" but it's certainly not wrong.